# Translation of maxHeight, scrollHeight to jquery height

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to translate a javascript function I saw into a jquery one. The problem seems to be with the translation of 'nameoftheconst'.css.maxHeight and another one which is 'scrollHeight'.
This is what the original code looks like :

```
const accordionItemBody = accordionItemHeader.nextElementSibling;
if (accordion.ItemHeader.classList.contains("Active")) {
  accordionitemBody.style.maxHeight = accordionitemBody.scrollHeight + "px";
} else {
accordionitemBody.style.maxHeight = 0
}
```

and this is where I am at the moment in the translation (note that I haven't put all the JS original one that is a bad quality picture but I think the logic is there). I couldnt translate the last part so did this nextitem.css.height = 1 // = 0 logic which doesn't do much.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".accordeon-item-header").click(function() {
        let nextitem = $(this).next()
        $(this).toggleClass("Active")
        if ((this).classList.contains("Active")) {
          nextitem.css.height = 1
        } else {
          nextitem.css.height = 0
        }
      })
    })
```

and this is the CSS:

```
.accordeon-item-body {
  max-height : 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition : max-height 0.3s ease-out
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Edit :
not so elegant solution but working :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".accordeon-item-header").click(function() {
        let nextitem = $(this).next()
        $(this).toggleClass("Active")
        if (!(this).classList.contains("Active")) {
         nextitem.css('max-height', '800px')
        } else {
          nextitem.css("max-height", 0)
        }
      })
    })
```

Comment: You *could* convert the jquery object to a dom node with `nextitem[0].css...` or use `nextitem.css("height", 1)`

Comment: Thanks, modified it a bit and worked